# Resolution: Keep element in view while scrolling using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, resolution

I have to keep the element in view while scrolling. i have done it and it's working fine in all the browser, but not wise resolution wise.

```
   $(function() {
            var offset = $(".sysIcons").offset();
            var topPadding = 15;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $(".sysIcons").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".sysIcons").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
```

it's working fine in 1024 x 768, 1280 x 735,

But not in  1360X768, - problem is while scrolling till at the end of the window, it will not stop. continuously animate while scrolling.

please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you are looking for.

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/
Main site: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/
Github: https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints

Answer (score 6):

You don't need jQuery to get element in view while scrolling, you can use CSS `position` property to make it appear all the time including scrolling:

```
#elementID {
  position:fixed;
  /* more styles */
}
```

`position:fixed` does not work in IE6 but who cares about it these days :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed` if you don't care about IE6.